# Where does Lenovo X1 2nd generation store its supervisor password?

Tags: bios, thinkpad, password-recovery

I have forgotten the supervisor password for my Lenovo X1 carbon 2nd. generation. Searching online I figured out how to remove the password for 1st generation X1 laptops. But I also read that unlike 1st generation X1, 2nd generation X1 does not store the BIOS password in an EEPROM. Where does 2nd generation store the password? Is there another chip on the system board which stores the password? Is there a way to remove the BIOS password in 2nd generation X1?

Comment: @Ramhound: www.ja.axxs.net

Answer (score 0):

Supervisor password does not give much protection. Its prevent random people from poking into your laptop's setup when you are not present but that is it. If someone has taken your laptop they can bypass the supervisor password so don't pick a complicated password for your bios.

The way to bypass the bios password to boot:
when booting if you have set a supervisor password the system will not allow you to boot unless you know the user password or the supervisor password. If you reset the user password it will not allow you to boot until you enter the supervisor password. However if you remove the battery which is located on the other side of your laptop then all this is gone. You can boot even without knowing the supervisor password.